# How to take value from cell in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a grid setter in javascript like this :

```
function AddMdrPymt(){
    var f = document.frmPL0011; 
    var grid = document.getElementById("mdrPymtGrid");
    var numRows = grid.rows.length;

    grid.insertRow(numRows);

    grid.rows[numRows].insertCell(0);
    grid.rows[numRows].insertCell(1);
    grid.rows[numRows].insertCell(2);
    grid.rows[numRows].insertCell(3);

    grid.rows[numRows].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' value='" + curRow + "' name='__mdrPymt' id='__mdrPymt'>";
    grid.rows[numRows].cells[1].innerHTML = "<table border='0' align='center'><tr align='center'><td><input type='text' onkeyPress='checkNumber(this)' name='txt_strtAmnt' id='txt_strtAmnt' class='" + txtclass + "' maxlength='18' size='25' fieldName='<%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_LoanStartAmnt", true)%>' onblur='checkData(this)' value = '" + val + "' "+dsb+"></td></tr></table>";
        grid.rows[numRows].cells[2].innerHTML = "<table border='0' align='center'><tr align='center'><td><input type='text' onkeyPress='checkNumber(this)' name='txt_endAmnt' id='txt_endAmnt' class='portlet-form-input-field' maxlength='18' size='25' fieldName='<%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_LoanEndAmnt", true)%>' onblur='checkData2(this)'></td></tr></table>";

curRow += 1;
```

And this is the grid HTML, the HTML code for the grid tittle, and the function above is function when user press add button

```
<table width="95%" align="center">
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <input name="addBtn" id="addBtn" type=button class='btn' onmouseover="this.className='btnHov'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" value="<%=LangFormatter.getString("button_add",true)%>" onclick="AddMdrPymt()" tabindex="4">
                        <input name="delBtn" id="delBtn" type=button class='btn' value="<%=LangFormatter.getString("button_dlt",true)%>" onclick="delMdrPymt()" onmouseover="this.className='btn btnHov'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" tabindex="5">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>                
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" name="mdrPymtGrid" id="mdrPymtGrid" class="grid" width="95%">
                            <thead class="header">
                                <th width="1%"></th>
                                <th width="20%"><%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_LoanStartAmnt",true)%></th>
                                <th width="20%"><%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_LoanEndAmnt",true)%></th>
                                <th width="20%"><%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_FixAmntInd",true)%></th>
                                                                <th width="20%"><%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_FixCashAmnt",true)%></th>
                                <th width="20%"><%=LangFormatter.getString("PL0011_CashbackLoanAmnt",true)%></th>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="addBtn" id="addBtn" type=button class='btn' onmouseover="this.className='btnHov'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" value="<%=LangFormatter.getString("button_add",true)%>" onclick="AddMdrPymt()" tabindex="6">
                        <input name="delBtn" id="delBtn" type=button class='btn' value="<%=LangFormatter.getString("button_dlt",true)%>" onclick="delMdrPymt()" onmouseover="this.className='btn btnHov'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" tabindex="7">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How to get value from txt_strtAmnt ?

Thank you

Comment: `document.getElementById('txt_strtAmnt').value`

Comment: Trying to find relation between code you posted and question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code snippet to get the TABLE > TR > TD HTML elemnt value : -

/* To get any TD element value. If one input type inside TD element.
 No need to mention the id name as we are getting the value using Tag Name.   */

```
var grid = document.getElementById("mdrPymtGrid");
var tableRows = grid.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var j = 0 ; j <= tableRows.length; j++){
    var tds = tableRows[j].getElementsByTagName("td");
     for (var k = 0 ; k <= tds.length; k++){  
     var strtAmntVal = tds[k].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;   
     break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grid with multiple rows then solution provided by @Arun will not work,
To make it work 
1)find grid element first with document.getElementById('gridid');
2)iterate through its children
3)in that iteration loop find document.getElementById('txt_strtAmnt').value

I am sure that will help you !
also we can achieve through JQuery if you want

Comment: can u tell me, how is it?

Comment: Will you able to post the whole grid html ? also, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: if my solution provided you the answer you need ,you can mark it as answer

Comment: i stil dont get it with this part "2)iterate through its children"

Comment: I have made assumptions and my answer was on assumption,too. If you can provide the HTML and your goal I can fix whatever you want to achieve. iterate through means for loop for all the grid rows (children of the grid) and for each grid row you can do operation for your textbox

Comment: i have edit my post with my full HTML function, is it enough?

Comment: I can't see HTML. where is your 'mdrPymtGrid' grid ? it's just javascript functions I can see which was present previously

Comment: Buddy I am confused what you want ?
Code you provided is not HTML it is some language code. please provide pure HTML. As per my understanding you want to add the row to existing grid collection or extracting the row from the grid collection ?


Use Jsfiddle for that

Comment: whatever I was trying to make you understand is exactly @Saroj wrote here

Comment: @Beginner what is the difference between mine answer and saroja's answer. I mentioned you the same thing that he mentioned. then why not accepting my answer as right one?